# Azure Data lake File Name mapping with target

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load the files from ADL using metadata in Azure Data Factory, I need to pass FileName of to the target table. Please suggest what would be the approach.

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [GetMetadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#metadata-options) in Azure Data Factory, from this [supported list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-connectors), it supports ADL connector.

[image]

The GetMetadata result is shown in activity output. To use the result in subsequent activity, use the pattern of `@{activity('MyGetMetadataActivity').output.itemName}`.

Comment: Yes, Used the same and passed filename into SP. Thank you

Comment: @Sra1K Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!